# Why do I get git merge conflicts?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I've encountered a situation related to git and Bitbucket which I don't understand.

I created a branch `branchB` that originated from `master`. I made some commits and created a pull request to `master`. While this pull request was being reviewed, I started to work on another feature which was an extension of the feature from `branchB`. So I created another branch (`branchC`) that originated from `branchB`. When my extended feature was ready, I created a pull request to `branchB`. See the **Picture I**. I didn't have any merge conflicts at the time.

[image]

I wanted to allow the reviewers to have a look at both pull requests separately and have separate pull requests with smaller changes.

My plan was the following:

- merge the pull request 1 (`PR1`) to master using the `--squash` option
- change the target branch in the pull request 2 (`PR2`) to master (See the **Picture 2**)
- merge the pull request 2 (`PR2`) to master

However, when I merge the pull request 1 (`PR1`) to master using the `--squash` option,  Bitbucket automatically changed the target branch of the pull request 2 (`PR2`) to `master` and I got some conflicts in  the pull request 2 (`PR2`).

So I resolved the conflicts:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull`
3. `git checkout branchC`
4. `git rebase master`
5. `git mergetool`
6. I resolved all conflicts here.
7. `git rebase --continue`

Actually, the described problem happened to me twice, since I also had `branchD` originating from `branchC`. When I merged `branchB` into `master`, I had to resolve some conflicts in the step 6. However, when I merged  `branchC` into `master`, I didn't have to resolve any conflicts manually in the step 6 (even though Bitbucket showed me merge conflicts, so I had to rebase `branchC`).

Mu questions are the following:

1. **Why did Bitbucket show me any merge conflicts for `PR2` when I merged `PR1` to master using the `--squash` option?** I'd expect it to figure out that the change between pictures `I` and `II` is only in commit ids - the code is hasn't changed. Git/Butbucket should be able to figure out which changes I want to make.
2. **Why didn't I get any conflicts that should be resolved manually when I was rebasing `branchD` into `master` (after I merged `branch C` into `master`)?** Since Bitbucket couldn't merge my pull request, I'd expect that I'd need to resolve some conflicts manually. Can it be related to git version on my desktop and on Bitbucket?
3. **Did I have any better option than creating these three pull requests in my case?** Could I have avoided these merge conflicts?

Additional information:

- git version on my desktop: `2.17.1.windows.2`
- Bitbucket version: `v5.12.2`
- git version on the Bitbucket server: `2.14.5`
- I looked for similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325086/why-i-get-merge-conflict), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514296/bitbucket-and-merge-conflicts), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385887/why-do-i-get-a-merge-conflict)). None of them deals with my problem.

I'd appreciate any explanation of this phenomena.

**Edit:**
1. I merged all my pull requests using the `--squash` option. 
2. I updated the picture to show that `branchB` and `branchC` do not start with commits `B1` and `C1`, respectively.

Comment: One point of clarification: a branch points at a particular commit and contains all of the commits prior to it. I note this because where you label `branchB` and `branchC` make it appear as if that's where these branches start. This is not accurate because both branches start at commit A1. I believe you mean that `branchB` ends at commit B2 and `branchC` ends at commit C2.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, you're right. I didn't mean to suggest that `branchB` and `branchC` start with commits `B1` and `C1`.  I had lines that connect commits `A2`- `B1` and  `B2`- `C1` on my picture to show that all branches contain commits from `master`. I updated the picture- hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand You situation correctly. The problem was this `--squash`. Here is the topic that explains how are the merges done in GIT [How does git know which version of a line to keep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350914/how-does-git-know-which-version-of-a-line-to-keep).

When You merged with `--squash`, since git commits are actually immutable, You have created a new squashed commit with new ID. When You wanted to merge `PR2` back to master, the file contents were changed in both places. For `branchB` there was a number of commits with some IDs and for `master` there was only one commit that had a different ID and some files were changed on both branches, so basically git has no idea which version is correct. This is why there were no conflicts in case of `branchC`, because the history of commits was the same for `branchB` and `branchC` (no `--squash` done here).

Comment: To OP and future visitors: Note that it doesn't matter that the squashed commit has the same textual changes as the original sequence of commits. Git sees two different sequences of changes and calls it a merge conflict.

Comment: If the contents of those two branches would be exactly the same, the different commit history itself would not create the merge conflict.

Comment: so in this case, do you mean that merging `branchC` into `master` (after PR1 was merged) considered the cumulative changes of commits B1 through C2? These changes are different than just A3 in isolation.

Comment: I mean that If You would reset `branchC` to the commit `B2`, so that the changes done in `master` and `branchC` are exactly the same. If You would merge the `branchC` into master, git would be able to do this without conflicts, even though the commit history is technically different. At least I was able to do this without conflicts in the situation described above.

Comment: So what about when `branchC` is at commit `C2` and `master` is at commit `A3` and you attempt to merge `master` into `branchC`. Why doesn't git determine that `A3` is identical to the changes in commits `B1` and `B2`?

Comment: The post I've pasted explains it I guess. The GIT does not really look at the commits from history. It will look at hashes of last changes and they will not match at the point. So it will try to compare files line-by-line and it will find out that there are indeed differences, so it will mark them as conflicts.

Comment: @DominikWosiński, this answers my first question. What about the second one? Why did I have to resolve some conflicts manually for PR2 and I didn't have to do it for PR3? All 3 pull requests were merged using the `--squash` option.

Comment: What is `PR3` in this case ?:)

Comment: It's the pull request from `branchD` to `master` that I merged after I merged the pull request from `branchC` to `master`. In fact, I had three branches: `branchB`, `branchC` and `branchD`. I didn't put `branchD` on the picture to make it simple. I mentioned it in my question.

Comment: This situation can occur if the changes in `branchD` were not conflicting with the ancestor. This means that the files modified in `branchD` were not the same as those modified in `branchC`. In such case three way merge is able to merge them correctly.